# Keras SimpleRNN input shape and masking

Tags: nlp, neural-network, keras

Newbie to Keras alert!!!

I've got some questions related to Recurrent Layers in Keras (over theano)

1. How is the input supposed to be formatted regarding timesteps (say for instance I want a layer that will have 3 timesteps 1 in the future 1 in the past and 1 current) I see some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136562/python-keras-simplernn-wrong-number-of-dimensions-on-model-fit) and the API proposing padding and using the embedding layer or to shape the input using a time window (3 in this case) and in any case I can't make heads or tails of the API and SimpleRNN examples are scarce and don't seem to agree.
2. How would the input time window formatting work with a masking layer?
3. Some related answers propose performing masking with an embedding layer. What does masking have to do with embedding layers anyway, aren't embedding layers basically 1-hot word embeddings? (my application would use phonemes or characters as input)

Comment: I suggest you add more information to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can start an answer, but this question is very broad so I would appreciate suggestions on improvement to my answer.

1. Keras SimpleRNN expects an input of size (num_training_examples, num_timesteps, num_features).

For example, suppose I have sequences of counts of numbers of cars driving by an intersection per hour (small example just to illustrate):

```
X = np.array([[10, 14, 2, 5], [12, 15, 1, 4], [13, 10, 0, 0]])
```

Aside: Notice that I was taking observations over four hours, and the last two hours had no cars driving by. That's an example of zero-padding the input, which means making all of the sequences the same length by adding 0s to the end of shorter sequences to match the length of the longest sequence.

Keras would expect the following input shape: (X.shape[0], X.shape[1](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3086), 1), which means I could do this:

```
X_train = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
```

And then I could feed that into the RNN:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(units=10, activation='relu', input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
```

You'd add more layers, or add regularization, etc., depending on the nature of your task.

For your specific application, I would think you would need to reshape your input to have 3 elements per row (last time step, current, next).

1. I don't know much about the masking layers, but [here is a good place to start](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3086).
2. As far as I know, embeddings are independent of maskings, but you can mask an embedding.

Hope that provides a good starting point!